# Perl CMS for nginx - with template, stylesheet, and navigation

Tags: linux, perl, sqlite, nginx

I'm looking for a Perl based CMS which would have:

- A template file to edit site layout. The template would have some keywords to add:

  - site title
  - site navigation (a vertical tree-view list of sections with selected current page)
- A style-sheet file to edit the style
- Optionally a non-daemon back-end (SQLite or flat file)
- nginx support
- integrated types of pages: page, contact form, (optionally bug tracker)

I looked at WebGUI, but it requires MySql and Apache, relying on some of its modules; it also has a extessive GUI while I only need page edit, template edit, and CSS edit tools, and a settings panel.

Searched at http://www.cmsmatrix.org/matrix/cms-matrix?func=search for Perl language + Open-source license, but I didn't come up with anything conclusive.

I like http://www.cmsimple.org/archives/cmsimple_old/?CMSimple:Awards but it's not in Perl.

I looked at:

- [Lightweight Perl CMS](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1013970):

  - Sub-thread [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1015200) suggests that Galileo doesn't have TOS/Navigation feature for me to put in sidebar.
  - I didn't find a navigation-in-sidebar feature for [Contenticious](https://metacpan.org/module/Contenticious).
- [Suggestions on Perl CMS](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=498079) - has a few suggestions.

  - [Bricolage](http://bricolagecms.org) [relies](http://bricolagecms.org/docs/current/api/Bric%3a%3aAdmin#Quick-Installation-Instructions) on Apache modules.
  - [Krang](http://www.krangcms.com/) looks good, but requires mysql.
  - [Big Medium](http://bigmedium.com) is not free.
  - [cyclone3](http://www.cyclone3.org) uses an XUL admin interface, but I think it must be web-based.
  - [WebAPP](http://www.web-app.net/) is not maintained that I can see. I don't like CGI (AFAIK this means the entire app is compiled for every user visit; it's slow). I didn't even find an Install or Requirements page.

Comment: As the author of Galileo, I hope that eventually it will be a full-featured CMS capable of most of your needs. In fact many of your reasons were why I started the project: there is no obvious Perl CMS! Sadly, as I develop it in my free-time and don't have much of that, its taking some time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems exactly this question was raised on Perl Monks only recently, so that could be a good place to start:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1013970

Comment: Updated question: I already visited that page while doing my search.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it will cover everything that you need, but i think that [Galileo](https://metacpan.org/module/Galileo) could be a good option.